# Ms VS2017 with SSDT has the 'User with Password' template but thinks it's wrong

Tags: sql-server, ssdt

In my database project when I choose the 'User with Password'  template in the Add New Item dialog, code is generated, kind of

```
CREATE USER [u2]
    WITH PASSWORD = 'jbniq_ushfbwc=l5nAxu8aapmsFT7_&#$!~<Jt}ho_aypip@'

GO

GRANT CONNECT TO [u2]
```

And it's immediately marked as having syntax error:

```
SQL46010: Incorrect syntax near 'jbniq_ushfbwc=l5nAxu8aapmsFT7_&#$!~<Jt}ho_aypip@'.
```

VS 2017 Comminity with SSDT 15.1.61903
Shoud I change some project settings or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Aaron mentioned in the comments, try enabling containment in the database settings:

[image: screenshot of ssdt settings]

That's after right-clicking the database project and choosing "properties" in Visual Studio.

If you are not using [contained databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/contained-databases?view=sql-server-2017), use the "User" script template instead of the "User with Password" script template.